# Pass Object to Function Method

Tags: jquery, iife

I have the following two immediately invoked functions:

```
var myCart = function() {
 var cart = [];

 var addToCart = function (item) {
   cart.push(item);
 }

 $(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var item = $(this);
   addToCart ({
     ProductId: item.attr("data-id"),
     Name: item.attr("data-name"),
     Price: item.attr("data-price"),
     Quantity: 1
   });
 });

 return {
  addToCart: addToCart()
 }
}();

var MyOtherFunction = function (myCart) {
  $('.my-other-selector').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $(this);
    myCart.addToCart ({
      ProductId: item.attr("data-id"),
      Name: item.attr("data-name"),
      Price: item.attr("data-price"),
      Quantity: 1
    });  
  });
}(MyCart);
```

I want to add an item to the cart from `MyOtherFunction` but no item gets added to the cart. How can I pass the item object into the `addToCart` method when it's called from `MyOtherFunction`?

Whats the best way to structure these functions so that I can call them from inside other functions?

Comment: There is syntax error, click event snippet isn't closed properly. secondly you are resetting cart every time with    var cart = []; correct these two changes and check

Comment: you also declare a function with no arguments var myCart = function() and calling it with a parrameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 return {
    addToCart: addToCart()
 }
```

Replace the above with the following:

```
return {
   addToCart : addToCart
}
```

You dont need `()` when assigning a function to a variable. Also you need to wrap your function in `()` like `var myCart = (function() {})();`  So your code become as follows:

```
 var myCart = (function() {

    var cart = [];

    var addToCart = function (item) {
       cart.push(item);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var item = $(this);
        addToCart ({
           ProductId: item.attr("data-id"),
           Name: item.attr("data-name"),
           Price: item.attr("data-price"),
           Quantity: 1
       });
    });

    return {
       addToCart: addToCart
    }

})();
```